# error reading kafka source - spark 3.0.0 k8s : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I run spark streaming app in k8s spark operator.

Spark version 3.0.0.
Read data from kafka - spark-sql-kafka-0-10.
I am not have any BigQuery dependencies, but in log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:44)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:255)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl$(TraversableLike.scala:249)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterImpl(Traversable.scala:108)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter(TraversableLike.scala:347)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter$(TraversableLike.scala:347)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:644)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:194)
at ru.neoflex.okb.population.reporting.subject.program.realation.utils.KafkaSourceConfigurable.kafkaSource(KafkaSourceConfigurable.scala:13)
at ru.neoflex.okb.population.reporting.subject.program.realation.SubjectToProgramRelationLoader.run(SubjectToProgramRelationLoader.scala:20)
at ru.neoflex.okb.population.reporting.subject.program.realation.SparkApp$.main(SparkApp.scala:5)
at ru.neoflex.okb.population.reporting.subject.program.realation.SparkApp.main(SparkApp.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class
```

In DataSourceRegister at jar only:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource
org.apache.spark.sql.v2.avro.AvroDataSourceV2
org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider
```

At local run - everething ik ok, but in kubernetes that issue.

```
./spark-submit 
--name spark-test 
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0 
--class ru...SparkApp 
--conf spark.executor.instances=3 
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark 
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark3  
..
--conf spark.master=k8s://https://master.infra:8443 
 local:///opt/spark/reporting-loader.jar
```

My job dependendencies

```
val core      = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core"           % Version.spark % Provided
val sql       = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"            % Version.spark % Provided
val streaming = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming"      % Version.spark % Provided
val sqlKafka  = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % Version.spark
val avro      = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro"           % Version.spark
val productModel = "ru.....schema" %% "trigger" % Version.productModels
val deltaLake = "io.delta" %% "delta-core" % Version.deltaLake
val pureConfig = "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % Version.pureConfig
val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % Version.scalaTest % Test
```

Assembly settings

```
  val assemblySettings = Seq(
assembly / assemblyOption := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false),
assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

)

Comment: The error suggests your Spark version is mismatched somewhere. For example, what docker images are being ran in k8s?

Comment: @OneCricketeer docker image is official for spark 3

Comment: Did you use maven/sbt for your jar? Can you show the other dependencies?

Comment: @OneCricketeer sbt, add deps in question

Comment: So, you shouldn't need the --packages if your uber jar contains that. But the jar you're providing is the uber jar right? I'm not super familiar with sbt, but maven outputs two jar files with some of its plugins

Answer (score 0):

Can run OK on local model, but encounter error when run on cluster, error log shows  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class".

Obviously, spark cluster missing jar dependencies "spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar".
Try to upload all maven dependencies of your reporting-loader.jar to your cluster.

Comment: spark-core_2.12-3.0.0.jar include, what reason to add  "spark-core_2.11-2.4.3.jar" if app use 3.0.0 spark ?